# Как сгенерировать на C++ атрибут Date в разметке EBML (контейнер webm / matroska)?

Tags: c++, datetime, .webm

Видео сервер пишет на диск входящие стримы, и в каждый файл теперь надо ставить временную метку стрима.

Согласно [документации](https://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html) атрибут Date это:

> Date - signed 8 octets integer in nanoseconds with 0 indicating the
>   precise beginning of the millennium (at 2001-01-01T00:00:00,000000000
>   UTC)

Вставил данный атрибут через MKVToolNix в тестовый файл и не могу понять, как это утверждение из документации сопоставить с вот этими данными:

[image: ebml_date]

То есть, hex `08 4F 27 F2 FA 64 20 00` это 21:00 22.12.2019 UTC (порядок байт скорее всего обратный) - **как это значение получить на плюсах?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача сводится к тому, чтобы получить количество наносекунд, прошедших с момента `2001-01-01T00:00:00,000000000 UTC` до какого-то другого определённого момента.

Для этого воспользуемся `std::chrono::system_clock`. Время, измеряемое этим типом часов, может быть соотнесено с календарным временем (в отличие от `std::chrono::steady_clock`).

Создадим структуру `std::tm`, заполним её необходимыми значениями времени. Из этой структуры с помощью `std::mktime()` можно получить `std::time_t`. А уже из `std::time_t` можно получить момент времени на часах `std::chrono::system_clock` с помощью `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t()`.

После этого приводим разницу этих моментов времени к наносекундам с помощью `std::chrono::duration_cast` и получаем это количество, вызывая метод `count()`.

Полученное значение и есть количество наносекунд, которое вы можете записать в файл.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    //2001-01-01T00:00:00,000000000
    std::tm begin_cal_time {};

    begin_cal_time.tm_year = 2001;
    begin_cal_time.tm_mon = 1;
    begin_cal_time.tm_mday = 1;

    //Начальный момент времени на часах system_clock
    const auto begin_tp = system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&begin_cal_time));

    //2019-12-22T21:00:00,000000000
    std::tm end_cal_time {};

    end_cal_time.tm_year = 2019;
    end_cal_time.tm_mon = 12;
    end_cal_time.tm_mday = 22;
    end_cal_time.tm_hour = 21;

    //Конечный момент времени на часах system_clock
    const auto end_tp = system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&end_cal_time));

    //Разница моментов времени, выраженная в наносекундах
    const auto nano = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end_tp - begin_tp).count();

    std::cout << "Nanoseconds (dec): " << nano << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Nanoseconds (hex): " << std::hex << nano << std::endl;

    // Nanoseconds (dec): 598741200000000000
    // Nanoseconds (hex): 84f27f2fa642000
}
```

Заметьте, что на скриншоте дата - 22 декабря, а не 21, как вы указали в вопросе.

Comment: Благодарю! (да, опечатка в вопросе)